# Find the maximum number of words given the length.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Given that $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\Sigma = \{\text{a,b,c}\}$ how can we find the number of different words of length $\alpha$? I can see that the sequence of the words is not important, i.e. it can start off with and have any letter in its sequence which is random, and you have to reuse the letters. As a visual exercise I wrote down all possible words with maximum length $1$ which is equal to $3$, all possible words with maximum length $2$ which is equal to $13$ and all possible words with maximum length $3$ which is equal to $39$. But I'm looking for a way to make a formula that can calculate the maximum number of words that can be generated for any given the maximum length $\alpha$. I'm also thinking if I can include $\epsilon$ since $\alpha$ can be $0$.

Comment: What are the 13 possible words for max length 2? I see: $\{ aa, bb, cc, ab, ac, ba, bc, ca, cb \}$, what's more?

Comment: "you have to reuse the letters"? What are the 3 possible words with maximum length $1$?

Comment: If it's max length $2$, then you can also have words with length $1$, so you'd have $\{\text{a,b,c,aa,bb,cc,ab,ba,ca,ac,bc,cb}\}$

Comment: If you also count the empty word then the answer is $3^0+3^1+\cdots+3^{\alpha}$. In my answer you find a trick that makes it possible to find on an easy way a closed form for that.

Answer (score 1):

Let us denote $\lvert m \rvert$ the length of a word and $\Sigma_n = \{ m \mid \exists (m_1, \ldots, m_n) \in \Sigma^n, m = m_1 m_2 \ldots m_n \}$, words of length $n$ and then: $\Sigma^{*} = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \Sigma_n$, all words over $\Sigma$.

Now, let us denote $\Sigma_{\leq n}$ the words of maximum length $n$ as $\Sigma_{\leq n} = \bigcup_{i \leq n} \Sigma_i$.

We want the cardinal of $\Sigma_{\leq n}$, we have (because the union is disjoint):

\begin{align*}
\mathrm{card}\, \Sigma_{\leq n} & = \sum_{i=0}^n \mathrm{card}\, \Sigma_i
\end{align*}

Let us denote $N_i = \mathrm{card}\, \Sigma_i = \left(\mathrm{card}\, \Sigma\right)^i$, let us denote $M = \mathrm{card}\, \Sigma$.

Now, we have: $\mathrm{card}\, \Sigma_{\leq n} = \dfrac{M^{n + 1} - 1}{M - 1}$.

We can see for $M = 3$ and $n = 2$, we have $13$, which is the result we expected.

If you want to exclude $\varepsilon$ the empty word, just sum from $1$ to $n$.

Comment: I can follow this method until the halfway mark. Could you explain where $N_i$ is used and how you got it to equal $(|\Sigma|)^i$ and how that led you to your formula?

Comment: @CuriousCar Sorry, $N_i = M^i$ is used in the sum, $N_i$ is the number of words with exactly $i$ letters, this is obviously the cardinal of $\Sigma$ raised to $i$-th power, because you just select $i$ times a letter of $\Sigma$ to get such a word, then the rest is a geometric sum.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$(3^0+3^1+\cdots+3^{\alpha})(3-1)=3^{\alpha+1}-1$

Comment: I'm assuming the powers indicate the maximum length of the words, but where did you get the $(3-1)$ and why would you multiply them?

Comment: Also if we have $\alpha = 2$ then the formula gives the number of words to be $26$ when it should be $12$.

Comment: If on LHS the brackets are removed in calculation then it becomes clear *immediately* that LHS equals RHS (that is the essential point). Then you are not ready yet (so I speak of a hint). Dividing both sides by $2$ gives $3^0+3^1+\cdots+3^{\alpha}=\frac12(3^{\alpha+1}-1)$. You are saying it should be $12$ for $\alpha=2$ but it becomes $13$ here because also the *empty word* is counted.

Comment: Oh I thought you went from the LHS to the RHS directly. But where di the $(3-1)$ come from?

Comment: That is a trick for proving on a handsome way that $$1+r+r^2+\cdots+r^n=\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}$$Multiply $1+r+r^2+\cdots+r^3$ with $r-1$. That results in $r^{n+1}-1$ in a very obvious way and after that you find that $1+r+r^2+\cdots+r^3=\frac{r^{n+1}-1}{r-1}$ by dividing both sides with $r-1$.